# Is it posible to get a model's unicode from another model?

Tags: python, django, unicode, models

I have two tables, `Housing` and `Photo` (one to many relationship).
The housing table returns unicode depending on type and transaction fields. I want the `Photo` unicode to be the `Housing`'s unicode + it's own primary key. Is this possible?

```
class Housing(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    transaction = models.CharField(max_length=16)


    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.type.lower() == "house" and self.transaction.lower() == "sell":
            return "HS" + str(self.pk+100)
        elif self.type.lower() == "house" and self.transaction.lower() == "rent":
            return "HR" + str(self.pk+100)
        elif self.type.lower() == "apt" and self.transaction.lower() == "sell":
            return "AS" + str(self.pk+100)
        elif self.type.lower() == "apt" and self.transaction.lower() == "rent":
            return "AR" + str(self.pk+100)
        else:
            return "ERROR" + str(self.pk+100)

class Photos(models.Model):
    housing= models.ForeignKey(Housing)
    photo_url = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/", blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Img " + str(self.pk)
```

Comment: As an aside, you should probably avoid putting complex logic in the `__unicode__` method. Better to put it in a separate method and then just call that from `__unicode__`.

Comment: Thanks will do, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reference the related `self.housing` object attributes, or convert it to Unicode:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"Img({!r}, {})".format(self.pk, self.housing)
```

This puts the output of `self.housing.__unicode__()` into the generated Unicode string after the primary key. This works because interpolating into a `unicode` string object with `unicode.format()` automatically will use `unicode(self.housing)`.

Your `Housing.__unicode__()` method can be simplified somewhat:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    if (self.type.lower() not in ('house', 'apt') or
           self.transaction.lower() not in ('sell', 'rent'):
        return 'ERROR{}'.format(self.pk + 100)
    type_, transaction = self.type[0].upper(), self.transaction[0].upper()
    return '{}{}{}'.format(type_, transaction, self.pk + 100)
```

Note that this does trigger a separate query for the `self.housing` relationship; if you are displaying a lot of `Photos` instances you can easily end up with one extra database query per `Photos` instance displayed, slowing down your application.

Comment: Thans @Martin Pieters. I tried this but couldn't get it to work. I found a way around it though, using the model's primary key.